# Xamarin Android custom action bar - something went wrong error

Tags: android, xamarin

I was trying to do exactly this tutorial for xamarin android: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/replacing-the-action-bar
okay so for the first time my project went good and I even created my custom bar but then I couldn't see the edit, save, overflow icons on the right of the menu, so I wanted to create the project again.
Now my problem is that I get the error Something went wrong in the designer - [Click on photo to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmiMM.png)
when I add this code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Can somebody help me, when I was doing project before it was working, now it is not and anyway I even got millions of errors when I try to do the project in other discs then C, why xamarin is bugged so much? I just need to create this app for studies..

DETAILS OF ERROR:
Indirect rendering enabled
Shadow-copying of Java assets took 97,194700 ms
Setting id 1 on newly created ClassLoader

> Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
>       Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
>       Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer
>       Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>       Trying to load class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
>       Trying to load class android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar
>       Bridge [resources.resolve] Couldn't resolve resource @layout/toolbar
>       Failed to process message Load
>       mono.android.DesignerException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>           at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:31)
>           at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:217)
>           at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:283)
>           at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:656)
>           at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>           at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find string resource matching value 0x3F1 (resolved name: layoutlib) in current configuration. Or the resolved value was not of type layout as expected.
>           at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1145)
>           at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1121)
>           at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getLayout(Resources_Delegate.java:497)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1155)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:140)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:900)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:859)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:271)
>           at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:270)
>           ... 4 more

Comment: The real exception is `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find string resource matching value 0x3F1`

Comment: still i dont understand how to fix it, i tried to do same tutorial on laptop, same error

Comment: when i first add the include layout,it gets the same issue, i only delete the content of the include and then fill it manually,it works,you could try to delet and fill again.

Comment: i tried to do it and it dont works :D but whatever i dont need a toolbar i just started to write bluetooth connection and for now its working great so im happy even when i dont have toolbar :D

Answer (score 0):

Rename "toolbar.xml" e.g to "app_toolbar.xml"